# What happened to Thor's shoulder wound in "Thor: Ragnarok"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

At the end of *Thor: Ragnarok*, after Thor becomes Electric Thor, there is a short scene where Thor tells Loki that Surtur's Crown/Eternal Flame is needed. Within 2-3 minutes, the scene after of Thor and Valkyrie vs Hela, Hela impales Thor with one of her spears. I re-watched it, and you can see it goes in one end and out the other.

What happened to his arm there or was it just forgotten about completely?

Comment: It should be noted that Hela is also stabbed straight through the torso when she fights the Asgardian forces just after she returns to Asgard and tries to convince them to bow to her as Queen. She seems just fine immediately afterwards as she continues slaughtering everyone.

Comment: He got better. Asgardians do that

Comment: Also, Thor is stabbed a couple more times by Hela just before he joins the fight on the Rainbow Bridge in the "What were you the god of again?" scene prior to, as you put it, him becoming "Electric Thor". https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQvhX-3CkJM Let's just say... Thor gets impaled a lot in this movie.

Comment: 'tis but a flesh wound.

Comment: And while we're at it, let's figure out how he can walk away from every fight with a perfect hairdo.

Comment: Mythical hair gel, obtained from the deepest well on Asgard...

Answer (score 2):

Whilst it does seem to have damaged him it was mostly a surface wound. Thor's body is turning with the spear so it ends up running almost parallel with him rather than straight into his body which minimises its effect.

[image: The tip of the spear is in Thor's right pec as his body turns away from it; he screams in pain]

When Hela then pulls on the spear and flings him away we get a clear look at his back where the spear should have come out and we don't see it so it didn't go through.

[image: Hela pulls on the spear and throws Thor away who is just about to start flying through the air; Hela has her arms in front of herself to protect from falling Thors]

If you watch the scene below, starting at 1:10, you see the spear falls out/off of him when he's flying through the air and then completely when he bounces off the Rainbow Bridge.

Later we get a close up of Thor as Surtur brings about Ragnarok, the area of his armour on his chest where the spear went in his clearly damaged.

[image: Valkyrie looks worried at Thor who watches Surtur rise of screen; his armour is damaged with a clear mark of where the spear hit him]

It's also worth noting that Thor has an incredibly high regenerative healing factor; much more so than other Asgardians. What little damage the spear actually did to him probably  didn't bother him for too long.

Comment: Worth noting that his 'regenerative healing factor' doesn't seem to replace missing bits.  So if he lost an arm, he'd probably not regrow it.

Comment: @Jeff Aye Aye!!